# pyspark - capture malformed JSON file name after load fails with FAILFAST option

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

To detect malformed/corrupt/incomplete JSON file, I have used FAILFAST option so that process fails. How do I capture corrupted file name out of 100s files because I need to remove that file from the path and copy good version of file from s3 bucket?

`df = spark_session.read.json(table.load_path, mode='FAILFAST').cache()`

Comment: I am able to get the file name but problem is I want to reload corrupt file with good file but since FAILFAST ends spark session , I am not able to use load again in exception handling.            `load_table()
  df = spark_session.read.json(file_name, mode='FAILFAST').cache()
except Exception:
  delete_old_file_copy_good_file(file_name)
  df = self.spark_session.read.json(file_name).cache()
  df.registerTempTable(table_name)`

Comment: I am able to get the file name but problem is I want to reload corrupt file with good file but since FAILFAST ends spark session , I am not able to use load again in exception handling. load_table() df = spark_session.read.json(file_name, mode='FAILFAST').cache() except Exception: delete_old_file_copy_good_file(file_name) df = self.spark_session.read.json(file_name).cache() df.registerTempTable(table_name)